# How to send multiple "SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID" in paypal payment

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

How to send multiple "SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID" in paypal payment, Is there any posibilities for to request multiple seller account ID.

For Eg.:
Where a customer added 3 different seller products in the cart and the customer process the payment for 3 seller products, Here how to send there seller paypal accout id to paypal.

Comment: Need help,If anyone known means kindly share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Paypal support this kind of Parallel payment flow.

Have a look at [Adaptive Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) document for more details.

Refer below links for input parameters and sample code.

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_parallel_payment/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: Ya i have seen that, But i don't know how to implement the code. And how to send the param.